# Can't understand why property from JS does not affect

Tags: vue.js

I have got JSON file that I iterate.

It have next structure:

```
{
"id": 4, "question": "Select one color", "answers": 
 [
    {"id": 1, "answer" : "Green", "isSelected" : false}, 
    {"id": 2, "answer": "Red", "isSelected" : false}, 
    {"id": 3, "answer": "Blue", "isSelected" : false},
    {"id": 3, "answer": "White", "isSelected" : false}
 ],
    "MaxAllowedChoice" : 2
}
```

I need to enable/disable all other items (checkboxs) if `MaxAllowedChoice` is reached.

I am iterate it's with next code:

```
      processOneQuestion: function (question)
      {
        var isSelectedCount = 0;

        for(var answer of question.answers) // just calculation
        {
          if(answer.isSelected)
          {
            isSelectedCount++;

          }
          console.log("isSelectedCount --> ", isSelectedCount);

        }

        for(var answer of question.answers) // Enabling/Disabling
        {

            if(isSelectedCount >= question.MaxAllowedChoice)
            {
              console.log("isSelectedCount : " + isSelectedCount + " | question.MaxAllowedChoice: " + question.MaxAllowedChoice);
              if(!answer.isSelected) // disable unselected
              {
                answer.isDisabled = true;
                console.log("answer.isDisabled = true");
              }

            }

            if(isSelectedCount !== question.MaxAllowedChoice ) // if MaxAllowedChoice less then isSelectedCount set iterated iterated answers isDisabled to false
            {
               if(!answer.isSelected) // disable unselected
               {
                answer.isDisabled = false;
                console.log("I hope that answer.isDisabled = false was added")

               }
            }
         }   

      }
```

HTML code:

```
        <div v-for="firstLevelAnswer in question.answers">                
      <label v-if="!question.isRadioButton"><span class="firstLevelAnswer"><input type="checkbox" class="big-checkbox" :disabled="firstLevelAnswer.isDisabled" v-model="firstLevelAnswer.isSelected" />{{firstLevelAnswer.answer}}</span></label> 
      <label v-if="question.isRadioButton"><span class="firstLevelAnswer"><input type="radio" class="big-checkbox" name="myvalue"/>{{firstLevelAnswer.answer}}</span></label>
      <span v-if="firstLevelAnswer.isTextInput"><input type="text"/></span>
           |  firstLevelAnswer.isSelected: {{firstLevelAnswer.isSelected}} 
           +>|  <span>{{firstLevelAnswer.isDisabled}}</span>
```

All work only if I add to JSON key: `"isDisabled" : false` like: 
    `{"id": 3, "answer": "White", "isSelected" : false, "isDisabled" : false}`

But I want add `"isDisabled" : false` property in JS dinamicaly.

But I can't understand what I am doing wrong and why items are not disabling. http://img.ctrlv.in/img/16/03/12/56e47dd115d82.png

It's look like property are added, but does not affect

I have got filling that because on start this property is not exists latter adding of it cause problem. Is it's possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would follow this logic. Everytime I select an option, I would check if I reached the maximum allowed limit.

```
checkDisabled: function() {
  var selectedCount = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i <= this.question.answers.length; i++) {
    if (this.question.answers[i].isSelected == true)
      selectedCount++;
  }

  (selectedCount >= this.question.MaxAllowedChoice) ? return true : return false;
}
```

Then use this method in your HTML to disable or enable the field.

Comment: Could you explain issue in my logic in my algorithm?